# How to get link of video from youtube using selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, youtube, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to make a program which can get the link of the video on youtube here is my code

```py
video=Song_name
chromeOptions=Options()
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs{'download.default_directory':down_pth}")
driver=webdriver.Chrome(path+"/chromedriver.exe",options=chromeOptions)
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,3)
presence = EC.presence_of_element_located   
visible = EC.visibility_of_element_located
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + str(video))
wait.until(visible((By.ID, "video-title")))
driver.find_element_by_id("video-title").click()
print(driver.current_url)
url=driver.current_url
print(url)
```

This code work only if the video on youtube comes on the first position on the list else it will fail if some ads come before(Top) of the video.
How can I avoid ads and play the video directly?
[Here is the image in which ads come on top of the video and I am not able to open video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5syEi.png)

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would navigate to the video URL page and use `.SendKeys()`

to send the `F6` key which will highlight the URL in full. Then I would send `Ctrl + C` to copy and you should be good to go!

Comment: your idea is nice But my program play first video out of many results, So what if my program play ads and get url of ads?

Comment: @SmitParmar how can you denote the main video from the rest?